# Wordpress SEO Yoast Double Query on Other Plugin issue

Tags: php, wordpress

i have simple wordpress shortcode plugin code below, and also i have Wordpress SEO Yoast enabled :

```
function simplefunc()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("insert into `anytable` (`column1`) values ('13')");
    return '';
}

add_shortcode( 'yourshortcode', 'simplefunc' );
```

and i'm executing, then the result was i have 2 entry in my `anytable`,

the query above run twice.

anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks,

Andi

Answer (score 0):

Even I had this issue on my [webiste](http://www.graphiccamp.com). I have deactivated the plugins and re-activated again. Then my problem got solved. Try and see yourself.

Comment: thanks, but not solved yet. still found 2 entry (twice insert), if without wordpres yoast seo plugin all fine.